# Packages and Modules in Python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why this architecture is not working ?

```
 /test
     __init__.py
     app.py
     models.py 
     /subpackage
         __init__.py
         subpackage.py
```

Here's the example code:

**app.py**

```
from test.subpackage import hi_from_subpackage    

hi_from_subpackage()
```

**subpackage/subpackage.py**

```
from test.models import models

def hi_from_subpackage():
    print('Hi')

# I nee models here too
models()
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test.subpackage import hi_from_subpackage
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.subpackage'**
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

-
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused with the import system of python, it happens. When you import subpackage, you want to import a module `subpackage` from a package `subpackage` so it should look like this:

```
from subpackage.subpackage import hi_from_subpackage
```

and when you are lower in the package hierarchy, you don't need to say witch package the module come from, it already "knows" it as it is in a higher hierarchy.

```
from models import models
```

Think about it like if you were writing core. Here models is in the scope of subpackage in a global variable way. And when you are standing in test package, you need to refer to a lower lever package by its name, as you do with a variable.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try running `pip install test` from your cmd if is Windows. With regard to the IDE you are using I would recommend vs-code to you.